# ABP localization resources from database

Tags: .net-core, abp, asp.net-core-localization

We are using ABP framework. How do I wire up localization resources (translations) from other source (e.g. database or some external API) rather than file.
In all examples it just shows how to add json file with resources.

```
options.Resources
            .Add<MetadataResource>("en")
            .AddBaseTypes(typeof(AbpValidationResource))
            .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/Metadata");
```

But how to wire up that all translations would be loaded from database?